# How to interpret a set of variables in an Erlang code line

Tags: erlang

I have been reading some Erlang function and came across something I do not understand. I have read the online manual (http://erlang.org/doc) but still don't understand.

In the line below, how is one supposed to read each of the variables?

```
#{Var1 := Var2} = Var3
```

The code I came across is this:

```
#{Namekey := Value} = FullNameRel
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is used for pattern matching in key value associations in maps, see [maps](http://erlang.org/documentation/doc-6.0/doc/reference_manual/maps.html).

For example,

```
mymap()->
    Key = 'Key',
    Map = #{Key => 'Old value', 'Key2' => 'Other value'},
    #{Key := Value} = Map,
    Value.  % returns 'Old value'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now it makes sense to me. I appreciate your help.